# How to limit instance count of firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I use following firebase cli command to deploy my firebase functions

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

How can I limit the number of instances for functions, when deployed like this? It looks like `gcloud` command has `--max-instances` option to limit instances, but couldn't find anything like this for firebase cli.

Comment: You may want to reconsider the accepted answer. I have just tried @nathan's solution and it works perfectly. The parameter is well documented in the link they provided. ^^

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the `maxInstances` when you write the function, using `runWith` and passing in [RuntimeOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/function_configuration_.runtimeoptions#optional-maxinstances)

Something like this:

```
 functions
.runWith({maxInstances: 3})
.https.onCall(() => {});
```

Comment: Updated Link:https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.runtimeoptions

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no option on the Firebase CLI for this.  Feel free to file a feature request with [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).  If such an option is added, it likely won't end up in the CLI, but rather the function [builder](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/function_builder_.functionbuilder) interface, similar to how region and memory are set.

For now, you can use the Google Cloud console by finding your deployed function there and editing to to use the value you want.

Comment: Couldn't find an option in google cloud console to change the instance count. I can only see options to copy function, test function, view logs and delete. Any idea where to edit the max instance count?

Comment: Click the edit button at the top to edit a deployed function after selecting it.

Comment: Found it! Thanks

Comment: The `maxInstances` option is not listed on the linked page for the `FunctionBuilder` interface, but it is listed on the page for the `RuntimeOptions` object, linked from the accepted answer. Probably the `FunctionBuilder.runWith` documentation should be updated! Also should probably be mentioned here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing a function with Python for 2nd gen Cloud Functions then you can use:

```
@https_fn.on_call(max_instances=10)
def foo(req: https_fn.CallableRequest) -> any:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For the latest Firebase V2, you can set maxInstances globally like this:

```
const { setGlobalOptions } = require("firebase-functions/v2"); // import it here

setGlobalOptions({ maxInstances: 10 }); // set it here

exports.helloWorld = onRequest((request, response) => {
  logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```